# Unexpected behaviour when passing None as a parameter value to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

Given the following test3 table

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[test3]    Script Date: 11/12/2023 9:30:17 AM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test3]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[test3]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[test3]    Script Date: 11/12/2023 9:30:17 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test3](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [column1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[test3] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test3] ([id], [column1]) VALUES (1, N'aaa')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test3] ([id], [column1]) VALUES (2, N'bbb')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[test3] OFF
GO
```

Problem:

The sqlstatement1 returns all two rows of the table.
The sqlstatement2 returns zero rows of the table.

```
import pyodbc

connectionString = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=7D3QJR3;DATABASE=mint2;Trusted_Connection=yes'
currentConnection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString) 

sqlStatement1 = '''
SELECT 
    id,
    column1
FROM test3
WHERE
    ISNULL(?, id) = id
ORDER BY 
    ID
    '''

sqlStatement2 = '''
SELECT 
    id,
    column1
FROM test3
WHERE
    ISNULL(?, column1) = column1
ORDER BY 
    ID
    '''

#Process sqlStatement1
sqlArgs = []
sqlArgs.append(None)
cursor = currentConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlStatement1,sqlArgs)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print('ROWS WITH ID=NULL:' + str(len(rows)))
cursor.close()

#Process sqlStatement2
sqlArgs = []
sqlArgs.append(None)
cursor = currentConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlStatement2,sqlArgs)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print('ROWS WITH COLUMN1=NULL:' + str(len(rows)))
cursor.close()
```

So why does it work with an int data type but not a string data type?

My gut is that the sp_prepexec statement is creating the positional parameter P1 as varchar(1) for some reason when the statement compares ? to a varchar column and sets P1 to and int when the statement comapres ? to a int column:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int',N'
SELECT 
    id,
    column1
FROM test3
WHERE
    ISNULL(@P1, id) = id
ORDER BY 
    ID
    ',NULL
select @p1
```

vs

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 varchar(1)',N'
SELECT 
    id,
    column1
FROM test3
WHERE
    ISNULL(@P1, column1) = column1
ORDER BY 
    ID
    ',NULL
select @p1
```

Comment: As a related note, a clause like `WHERE ISNULL(@P1, id) = id` isn't advisable. Instead you'd be better off with `WHERE @P1 = id OR @P1 IS NULL` and having `RECOMPILE` in the `OPTION` clause, or (even better) only having the `WHERE` in the query when the parameter *has* a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My gut is that the sp_prepexec statement is creating the positional parameter P1 as varchar(1) for some reason when the statement compares ? to a varchar column and sets P1 to and int when the statement comapres ? to a int column.

Yes that is exactly what it does. It has no knowledge of how large to make the parameter, because you haven't told it. This has been noted on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/213).

Because you are using it on the left side of an `ISNULL`, the right side is casted to the left side, hence the query is not giving the correct results.

You have a number of solutions:

- You can use `setinputsizes` to set the type and size of a string parameter:

  ```
  cursor.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR, 10, 0)])
  ```
- Do an explicit cast. This is a much better option, as it can never fail and you can set each value individually.

  ```
  WHERE
      ISNULL(CAST(? AS varchar(10)), column1) = column1
  ```

  You can also do this by setting it to a variable of the correct size first.
- Rewrite your query to not use `ISNULL`, which you should do anyway, because it prevents the use of indexes.

  - Either use an `OR`

    ```
    sqlStatement2 = '''
    SELECT 
        id,
          column1
    FROM test3
    WHERE
        (? = column1 OR ? IS NULL)
    ORDER BY 
        ID;
    '''
    ```

    Note that you need to pass the parameter twice, or assign it to a variable within the SQL.
  - Or **the best option in my opinion,** make the query dynamic, so you decide up front whether to filter by that column.

    ```
    sqlStatement2 = '''
    SELECT 
        id,
          column1
    FROM test3
    '''

    if someValue is not None:
        sqlStatement2 = sqlStatement2 + '''WHERE
          ? = column1
    '''

    sqlStatement2 = sqlStatement2 + '''ORDER BY 
        ID;
    '''
    ```

Note that in these last two options, it's probably still ideal to set the variable size.

Comment: I was hoping to try to stay away from dynamic strings if possible and get that the use of isnull on the left negates any indexes.  I wasn't a fan of passing the same parm twice, even tried the cursor.execute(sqlStatement1,[sqlArgs]*2) syntax but couldn't get that to work, and honestly, did not like it.  I know I could do this with an anonymous t-sql block but that seems overkill and messy.  I think I will try your casting going forward.  Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: `sqlArgs.append(None)` `sqlArgs.append(None)` is how you would do that

Comment: Excellent answer, as usual. One possible clarification, though: Some might (mis)interpret "[setinputsizes] sets it for all string variables" as meaning that all string parameters for the whole query will be sent as `varchar(10)`, when in fact it's just string parameters *for that column* (based on its position in the parameter list).

Comment: Ah sorry, I actually thought that's what it does. Fixed now.

Comment: Much better title than my OP.  Thanks all!